# IE9 32bit on Win7 64bit JavaScript and Flash do not work though IE9 64bit does

Tags: windows-7, javascript, internet-explorer-9

I am having this unusual issue with my system. It started with not being able to install the Microsoft Skydrive app and has snowballed.

I am running win7 professional 64 bit.
Adobe flash player is installed in the 64bit IE9 and works fine, as well as JavaScript and general browsing (This is not my main browser). Chrome, and FF work fine as well, however if I use the 32bit IE9 I am not able to run any JavaScript what so ever and adobe flash player states it is not installed even though I believe it is with the latest version of 11.4 integrating both 32bit and 64bit.

So how have I come to the belief that it is JavaScript? Well I noticed a few other simpler pages not work correctly so I guessed a few times and went to w3schools to test a simple JavaScript applet and it did not work.  I have gone to internet explorer --> Tools--> security and ensured that active scripting is enabled everywhere I can.

Things I have tried, uninstall - reinstall flash player and no matter what I do no dice. 
I've also tried an IE9 reset through the Microsoft site no dice. All my settings seem to be correct where do I go from here? I have reverted to previous versions of flash, and the new one.

Comment: Switch to chrome and never look back.

Comment: @rlemon - While this can often be a solution it sometimes is not possible.

Comment: Do you use Asus Xonar ?

Comment: @Justin - You do understand that Java and JavaScript are entirely two different thing right?  They have nothing to do with one another.  What version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: Have you tried disabling (uninstalling) IE from 'Add/Remove Windows components' and re-enabling it? @Ramhound it is only ever 'not possible' because some sys admin decided so. I would suggest talking to said admin so they can correct the issue or allow you to install a real browser.

Comment: @rlemon - There is nothing wrong with IE9 millions of people use it by choice.  I am one of those users.

Comment: http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/ Please read and then tell me there is nothing *wrong with IE9*...

Comment: I have tried uninstalling it to no avail, Yes I know Java and javascript are completely different. I have gone to http://enable-javascript.com/#ie and have completed these instructions to no avail.@rlemon I have removed the components before to no avail. @Dave Rook no.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

- Open the control panel
- internet options
- advanced tab
- then click reset button.

Comment: reset is always there to rescue. :)

Comment: Tried and it makes absolutely no difference.